# Equivalence relation on $\text{Prop}(A)$

Tags: logic

Given: $A = \{a_1, \dots , a_n\}, ~~ |A| = n$

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\text{Prop}(A)$ given by:

$$p \sim q : \iff \models  p \leftrightarrow q$$

Then the quotient set $\text{Prop}(A)/\sim$ is finite; determine its cardinality as a function of $n = |A|$

I did not quite understand the equivalence relation.. is it that $pRq$ iff $p \leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology?  But it only happens when $(p = \top \wedge q = \top) \vee (p = \perp \wedge q = \perp)$ so the cardinality is $2$ ? I am sorry if I misunderstood the question.. I would appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Comment: What is Prop(A)? The set of logical formulae in the variables (or propositions) given by $A$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I don't think I got it yet.. $\text{Prop}(A)$ is the set of propositions..

Comment: Consider something like $p=a_1$ and $q=a_1\vee a_1$. Then $pRq$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $A$ denotes a set of propositions (true or false) or a set of variables, then any well-formed propositional formula in $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ can be uniquely written in disjunctive normal form. There are at most $2^n$ disjunctive normal forms in $n$ variables (or propositions) and this should be the answer.

Comment: But what does the $ p \leftrightarrow q$ part has to do with the question then?

Comment: Its the equivalence of two propositions.

Comment: But what does it have to do with the question - I mean, how do we use it in the answer? If it's the equivalence of two prop, then the answer should be $2n$ no? There are $2n$ pairs..